# issue with passing array of dictionaries into function

Tags: ios, arrays, function, swift

Swift is new for me so I would appreciate your help.
I have an *array*:

```
let bankDict  = [
    ["bank": "b1", "currency": "c1", "buyrate": 0.11, "sellrate": 1.222, "officialrate": 2.15],
    ["bank": "b1", "currency": "c2", "buyrate": 3.11, "sellrate": 4.222, "officialrate": 5.15],
    ["bank": "b1", "currency": "c3", "buyrate": 7.11, "sellrate": 8.222, "officialrate": 9.15]]
```

I am trying to create a function which should return *buyrate*/*sellrate*/*officialrate* from my array `bankDict`.

So far I have created just a loop to test logic:

```
for dict in bankDict {
    let b = dict["bank"]!
    let c = dict["currency"]!

    if b == "b1" && c == "c2" {
        let br = dict["buyrate"]!
        let sr = dict["sellrate"]!
        let or = dict["officialrate"]!
        println("\(br) -> \(sr) -> \(or)")
    }
}
```

As expected returns me: `3.11 -> 4.222 -> 5.15`

When I am trying to create function:

```
func showRates (bnk: String, crnc: String) -> (br: Double, sr: Double, or: Double) {
    for dict in bankDict {
        let b = dict["bank"]!
        let c = dict["currency"]!

        if b == bnk && c == crnc {
            let br = dict["buyrate"]
            let sr = dict["sellrate"]
            let or = dict["officialrate"]
            println("\(br) -> \(sr) -> \(or)")
        }

        return (br, sr, or)
    }
}
```

I get an error: `use of unresolved identifier 'sr'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue of scope. `br`, `sr`, and `or` were defined in the scope of the *if-statement*:

```
if b == bnk && c == crnc {
    let br = dict["buyrate"]
    let sr = dict["sellrate"]
    let or = dict["officialrate"]
    println("\(br) -> \(sr) -> \(or)")
}
```

Therefore they are only useable within that block of code.
If you move the return statement to be part of the if-statement it works (with a few other adjustments):

```
let bankDict  = [
    ["bank": "b1", "currency": "c1","buyrate": 0.11, "sellrate": 1.222, "officialrate": 2.15],
    ["bank": "b1", "currency": "c2","buyrate": 3.11, "sellrate": 4.222, "officialrate": 5.15],
    ["bank": "b1", "currency": "c3","buyrate": 7.11, "sellrate": 8.222, "officialrate": 9.15]]

func showRates(bank: String, currency: String) -> (buyrate: Double, sellrate: Double, officialrate: Double)? {
    for dict in bankDict {
        if dict["bank"] == bank && dict["currency"] == currency {
            if let buyrate = dict["buyrate"] as? Double,
               let sellrate = dict["sellrate"] as? Double,
               let officialrate = dict["officialrate"] as? Double {
                return (buyrate, sellrate, officialrate)
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

[SwiftStub-Code](http://swiftstub.com/325385856/) (not the Swift 1.2 version yet)

Comment: I am afraid it is not working or I am doing something wrong:( http://swiftstub.com/980363852/

Comment: Here's your version fixed: http://swiftstub.com/229281236/
Here's my version: http://swiftstub.com/815194052/

Comment: still something is wrong cause function returns nil http://swiftstub.com/376288768/

Comment: You dont need one of returns in my version. By the way how to unwrap values? http://swiftstub.com/456023066/  Don't know how to fix yours version

Comment: Ah, there you go.
Here's a version that's a little safer: http://swiftstub.com/189943415/

Comment: Do you know how to unwrap values? Now it is (Optional(3.11), Optional(4.222), Optional(5.15))

Comment: Is the function ever supposed to be able to return some `nil`, and some actual values in the tuple? Or are all values supposed to be `nil`, or all have a value?

Comment: Function is not supposed to return nil. It should always return actual values

Comment: Well, that's not possible because you are using dictionaries, but in the end that means all or nothing I guess. So either (1, 2, 3) or (nil, nil, nil).
Therefore you could just declare the whole tuple as optional, instead of each value: http://swiftstub.com/857545158/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71380/discussion-between-almazini-and-marcus-rossel).

Answer (score 1):

Have you think what will happen if b is not equals to bnk or c to crnc? What should your function need to return in that case? If you want to return nil values then you can do the following

```
func showRates (bnk: String, crnc: String) -> (br: Double?, sr: Double?, or: Double?) {

for dict in bankDict {
    var b = dict["bank"]!
    var c = dict["currency"]!

    if b == bnk && c == crnc {
         var br = dict["buyrate"] as? Double
         var sr = dict["sellrate"] as? Double
         var or = dict["officialrate"] as? Double
         println("\(br) -> \(sr) -> \(or)")
         return (br, sr, or)
        }
}
return (nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Comment: I have tried to return 0,0 insted of nils. Your solution gives the error ( error: 'NSObject' is not identical to 'Double' ) Here is issue with conversion ... and I don't have enough knowledge to understand how it should be

Comment: Error:24:1: error: missing return in a function expected to return '(br: Double?, sr: Double?, or: Double?)'
http://swiftstub.com/552860976/

Comment: Sry my bad return (nil, nil, nil) should go after the for loop, I edited it again

Comment: Yes now it works! thanks a lot! By the way it returns "(Optional(3.11), Optional(4.222), Optional(5.15))" how should I unwrap values?